# Created Repository, what to reference in model relations?

Tags: php, laravel, model

To improve my Laravel development style, I looked at [this](http://dfg.gd/blog/decoupling-your-code-in-laravel-using-repositiories-and-services) article. So I created an Interface and Repository for my User model. But this model is related to the "topics" model. I created Interface and Repository for this one as well. But what do I need to reference in the relations? The model/entity itself or the interface/repository?

```
$id = 1;
$user = User::find($id);
$new_topics = $user -> topics() -> new();
```

Just a basic example of code I want to execute. So what do I need to reference? This is the User model:

```
/* The Model/Entity */
public function topics()
{
    return $this -> hasMany('App\Models\Entities\Topic');
}

/* OR */

/* The Interface */
public function topics()
{
    return $this -> hasMany('App\Models\Repositories\TopicInterface');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a Model to hasMany or other relationship methods available in Eloquent ORM . So the answer you are looking for is ,

```
/* The Model/Entity */
public function topics()
{
    return $this -> hasMany('App\Models\Entities\Topic');
}
```

What ever model you speficied in the hasMany function has to extend Eloquent
or the Relationship model will not work .

Answer (score 0):

The article you mention explains how to implement a facade that makes handling Entities more elegant, but it has nothing to do with the ORM part of Laravel which models de relationships between the entities. So when dealing with ORM you must reference the model classes and not the Repositories.
Therefore the answer to your question is

```
/* The Model/Entity */
public function topics()
{
    return $this -> hasMany('App\Models\Entities\Topic');
}
```